# AutoLisp - Each Document

Tags: autolisp

How does someone get the variable for each open instance of documents in a cad program?

```lisp
;; Gets the application
(setq objApp (vlax-get-acad-object))
;; Object collection of open documents
(setq objDocs (vla-get-documents objApp))

;; Each open document
(setq iCount (vla-get-count objDocs))
(setq iItr1 0)
(repeat iCount ; Also tried foreach
    ;; This is where I'm stuck 
    ;; ssname works with selection sets, not objects. 
    (setq objOpenDoc (ssName objDocs iItr1));---; <-Error
    (princ "\nDoc : ")(princ objOpenDoc)(terpri); Printing Results
    (setq iItr1 (1+ iItr1));--------------------; Next Document
);repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `repeat`, use [`vlax-for`](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-9CB1C7DD-7E25-4F8C-8858-D79FEC043BEC.htm#!). [`Vlax-for`](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-9CB1C7DD-7E25-4F8C-8858-D79FEC043BEC.htm#!) allows for collections within object variables to be individually passed into the symbol variable.

```lisp
;; Gets the application
(setq objApp (vlax-get-acad-object))
;; Object collection of open documents
(setq objDocs (vla-get-documents objApp))

;; Each open document
(vlax-for objOpenDoc objDocs
    (princ "\nDoc : ")(princ objOpenDoc)(terpri); Printing Results
);repeat
```

Result:

```lisp
Command: (progn (setq objApp (vlax-get-acad-object))(setq objDocs (vla-get-documents objApp))(vlax-for objOpenDoc objDocs (princ "\nDoc : ")(princ objOpenDoc)(terpri)))
Doc :  #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadDocument 85066cc0>
Doc :  #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadDocument 0828b3c0>
Doc :  #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadDocument 60e96430>
Doc :  #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadDocument 574d6760>
Doc :  #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadDocument 86b0e3b0>
Doc :  #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadDocument a5964cc0>
Doc :  #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadDocument cdf25490>
nil
```